# Buffer overflow: How to do a relative jump from ESP?

Tags: x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am trying to do an exercise in the area of a stack buffer overflow. I'm doing the classical example where the vuln allows you to overwrite EIP. My problem is that I can only use addresses starting with 00 which means I cannot overwrite addresses larger than what ESP is pointing to. So the classical approach of putting the shellcode after the address I'm overwriting EIP with won't work. Instead, I need to put the shellcode before the address into the buffer. See the simple drawing below.

```
<larger stack addresses>  ........... <smaller stack addresses>
    ESP                               Need to jump here somehow
     |                                  |     
     V                                  V
   XXXX|AAAA|AAAA|AAAA|AAAA|AAAA|....|AAAA|AAAA|AAAA|....
     A
     |
     |
    My buffer won't reach any  addresses
    larger than ESP because of the 0 in it...
```

Now the question is: What is the assembly instruction I need to search for that will jump to the address say 200 bytes smaller than ESP? I don't know x86 assembler well enough. I have tried everything like jmp [ESP-8], jmp [ESP-16], ... (also with larger offsets), then sub ESP,EBX + jmp ESP, xor ESP, EBX + jmp ESP and so on. I should add here that it looks like I can overwrite EBX as well. So if there was sub ESP,EBX + jmp ESP or sth like that, then I could fill EBX with the negative offset jump to the shellcode by subtracting the offset from ESP first. But whatever I try, I cannot find the instructions in the module. I think my main problem is that I don't understand x86 assembly language well enough. I have seen instructions like jmp DWORD PTR DS:[ESP+8] in the code and have been googling a bit and my limited understanding tells me that this is a relative jump in the data segment. So I would need to do something like this in the stack segment, ideally getting the offset from the EBX register... Does sth like this exist?

Comment: I am googling day and night for this thingy... and found something that might help. There are 2 interesting mona.py search commands: findwild and jmp.

Comment: You can most likely work around this by using ROP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indirect jumps to a value in a register can't take an offset.  You have to do all the address math before running the `jmp` instruction.  There is no way to encode `jmp  esp - 200` or anything like that.

`jmp [ESP-8]` would load from `[ESP-8]`, and jump to that address.  You can tell it's doing a load because it has square brackets.

So you should try looking for sequences like

```
lea   eax, [esp-200]
jmp   eax               # or call eax
```

Or

```
sub  esp, 200
jmp  esp
```

The AT&T syntax for register-indirect jumps is `jmp *eax`, BTW.

Those instructions don't have to be adjacent; you might find what you need for a [ret2reg](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157478/why-jmp-esp-instead-of-directly-jumping-into-the-stack) attack separated by a few instructions, but this is harder to search for because you need to limit your search to cases where decoding starts at a `sub`, `lea` or whatever, and gets to a `jmp` after some number of valid instructions that won't fault with the register values expected at the `ret` you're attacking.  You might try just starting disassembly from every every offset up to 20 bytes before a possible `jmp reg` or `call reg` instruction, and see if any offset produces valid instructions that do something interesting.

You don't necessarily have to find a sequence that starts with `esp`; if a pointer to somewhere else in the buffer exists in another register, you could look for a `jmp` or `call` to that register.

---

Doing `sub esp, 200` / `jmp esp` leaves the stack pointing to the lowest address of your code, so **`push`ing data onto the stack won't overwrite the end of your code before execution reaches it**, which could be a problem with long code that comes close to or past the original `esp`.

The stack grows down, but execution goes up towards increasing addresses, so if you start with EIP=ESP, you only get into trouble if you `pop` or otherwise increase ESP.